# Set two cookies with different domains for Django session

Tags: django, cookies

On our Django website SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN, by default, is "domain.com". Now we want to share user sessions between subdomains, and change SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to ".domain.com"

The known problem is that all sessions will be lost after this change.

Is it OK to return session cookie twice?

```
_sid=35d86431ff0e89cef1ea6806c5ebdbe9; Domain=.domain.com; Path=/
_sid=35d86431ff0e89cef1ea6806c5ebdbe9; Domain=domain.com; Path=/
```

We can modify session middleware for that, but will it solve the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to read cookies from two domains (fallback when there is no wildcard domain cookie) instead of setting two? I thing one (wildcard) cookie will be enough.

Comment: To set a cookie is just one set_cookie call. To read we need to dig into standard Django middleware.

Comment: @Jury: ran into a similar problem (need to share sessions between `www.example.com` and `example.com`). Like you, I don't want to lose all sessions. Did your way of setting session cookie twice work?